How to get rid of index title?
I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the index at the top of my page. I have tried using headerShown = {false} and it is not working. Below is my code
// index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'; // Import GestureHandlerRootView
import AppNavigator from './(tabs)/_layouts'; // or './layouts'

export default function InitialRouting() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

// _layouts.tsx

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../firebaseConfig';
import HomeStack from '../stacks/homeStack';
import ProfileStack from '../stacks/profileStack';
import GiveStack from '../stacks/giveStack';
import DiscoverStack from '../stacks/discoverStack';
import SignUpPage from '../signUpPage';
import LoginPage from '../loginPage';
import AuthenticationPage from '../authenticationPage';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabLayout() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = 'home';
          } else if (route.name === 'Discover') {
            iconName = 'search';
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = 'person';
          } else if (route.name === 'Give') {
            iconName = 'heart';
          }
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Discover" component={DiscoverStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Give" component={GiveStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function AppNavigator() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    });
    return subscriber; // Unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent = {true}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={TabLayout} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="AuthenticationPage" component={AuthenticationPage} />
            <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpPage} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}



I have tried using headerShown={false} and moving the navigation container between the two pieces of code, but neither has worked

the index title is likely derived from the component name or file structure update the screen options to change name eg:
<Tab.Screen 
    name="Home" 
    component={HomeStack} 
    options={{ title: 'Home' }}  // Custom title
/>


<Tab.Screen 
    name="Home" 
    component={HomeStack} 
    options={{ headerShown: false }} // No title for Home
 />

